# SQL Server - how to select while skipping other data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data with following data

[image]

In this round 1 and 2 is related with course 231 and 776.

But I need to select output as

[image]

means if round 1 selected with field 231, it must skip other row of round with 1 and also skip the row with field with 231.

But round 3 and 4 has single record, then it should be included in output.

How can I achieve this result?

thanks

EDIT:
in case of round 3 has multiple record, then it table would be like:

[image]

and needed output is:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what logic you use to skip rows. _"In this round 1 and 2 is related with course 231 and 776"_ I don't understand this either. _"if round 1 selected with field 231"_ What means selected?

Comment: How come you want 231 and not 776 for the (2018, 1) rows, and 776 instead of 231 for the (2018, 2) rows?

Comment: I **think** the OP wants the minimum value of the row, that wasn't the minimum value of the previous row, **unless** that row only has that value as a minimum... To be honest, that really does make no sense.

Comment: I want to select first occurrence of round and field, suppose if round 1 is selected the other record with round 1 should be skip, and same with field, if a round has records with multiple field then it must skip previous selected field. in this case round 2 must select field 776. and round 3 and 4 has single record, so it should select them.

Comment: @AbhinawKumarSingh What if Round 3 had both values (231 and 776) what would be returned then?

Comment: You must use a cursor to take in memory the previous choose

Comment: Don't use a cursor...

Comment: @Larnu please see the update post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't prefer to use cursor but for this situation, I couldn't provide a single query to retrieve desired output. So, you can try like this;

```
declare @round int
declare @field int
declare @selectedFields table (field int)
declare @expectedRounds table (Round int, field int)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select * from (
select Round,min(Field) as Field from SampleTable group by Round having count(*) > 1) Records order by Round

insert into @expectedRounds 
select Round,max(field) from SampleTable group by Round having count(*) = 1
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @round, @field   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       declare @selectedField int
       declare @selectedRound int
       select top 1 @selectedRound = Round, @selectedField = field from SampleTable where Round = @round and field not in (select field from @selectedFields) order by Field asc

       insert into @expectedRounds (Round, field) VALUES (@selectedRound, @selectedField)
       insert into @selectedFields (field) VALUES (@selectedField)
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @round, @field  
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

select * from @expectedRounds order by Round asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT [year]
    ,[round]
    ,MIN([field])
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY [year]
    ,[round]
ORDER BY [year]
    ,[round]
```

Comment: The OP says Round 2 should have a Field value of `776`. This would return `231`.

Comment: Oh you are right, but seems that the OP wrote it wrong, because first line should be 231 if the rule is first inserted line or something like that, that makes no sense :)